# How can I use Custom SQL with [other jdbc] for the tableau on hdp3.1

Tags: tableau-api, hdp

when i connected to the hdp3.1 use other jdbc,I can't use the custom sql with this error:
An error occurred while communicating with the data source.

Bad Connection: Tableau could not connect to the data source.
com.tableausoftware.jdbc.TableauJDBCException: Error reading metadata for prepared query: SELECT *
FROM (
  select boxid,boxserialno from "dw"."dim_boxinfo" limit 10
) Custom_SQL_Query
LIMIT 1 
Method not supported
There was a Java error.

Comment: Do you have other Tableau data sources that are connecting like this correctly? Or is this the first time you have tried this?

Comment: this is the first time